# upgraded horizon version, newly added tables is not synchronising with stellar core private network

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, assets, manageofferoperation, path-payment

Stellar core version is 12.2.0. Recently i upgraded my horizon version from 0.17 to 0.23. while running, it showed me an error that i need to "horizon db migrate up". Post doing that it basically added few more tables in my horizon database like "offers","trustlines","accounts_signers","accounts_data" etc.

I also have few offers in my stellar core node "offers" table. BUT , the horizon database "offers" table is totally empty.

i am running stellar private network. also running "--ingest=true" . in stellar configuration, below values is set for history

```
[HISTORY.vs]
get="cp /tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} /tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p /tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0}".
```